# How to make Mustache logic tags functional

Tags: c#, json, tags, mustache, nustache

I'm currently using C# to create/parse a JSON file and then using this to fill in a mustache template.

I've installed Nustache into VB using the NuGet package for Nustache.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "LinkName": "test",
  "TESTBOOL": true,
  "NodeProfileENUM": "TEST",
  "Requester": false,
  "Responder": false,
  "Nodes": {
    "Root": {
      "nodeName": "Root",
      "displayName": null,
      "type": null,
      "initialValue": null,
      "serializable": null,
      "className": null,
      "enumName": null,
      "isLast": true,
      "actionList": {}
    }
  },
  "LinkActions": {}
}
```

And in my template I've tried using Tags like:

```
{{#TESTBOOl}} test {{/TESTBOOL}}
```

but I keep getting an error saying the block isnt registered,

I've also tried iterating through the Nodes section:

```
{{#each Nodes}}
{{#each this}}
{{this.nodeName}}
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

but this isn't working either.

I'm parsing and rendering the json and template (C#) like this:

```
string nodeProfileFormat = File.ReadAllText("NodeProfileTemplate2.txt");

JObject parsedLinkTest = 
JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("LinkDefinitionTest.json"));

string nodeProfileResultTest = 
Nustache.Core.Render.StringToString(nodeProfileFormat, parsedLinkTest);

File.WriteAllText("NodeProfileTemplateResult.java", nodeProfileResultTest);
```

Is there anything I'm forgetting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your templates, use [moustache's demo](https://mustache.github.io/#demo). Your TESTBOOL template is working if you fix the typo:

```
{{#TESTBOOL}} test {{/TESTBOOL}}
```

If you want to display `nodeName` you have to do:

```
{{Nodes.Root.nodeName}}
```

Your json contains only object. Your Nodes is not an array. Maybe you are looking to iterate properties though.

About your C#, you can use Nustache `FileToFile` method:

```
var parsedLinkTest = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("LinkDefinitionTest.json"));
Nustache.Core.Render.FileToFile("NodeProfileTemplate2.txt", parsedLinkTest, "NodeProfileTemplateResult.java");
```

If it failed, check with the debugger if `parsedLinkTest` is well filled.